# How to adjust (bootstrapped) confidence intervals for multiple testing in R?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap, multiple-comparisons, lsmeans

I am comparing effects of different resources by comparing slopes implemented by interaction terms in (generalized) linear mixed effects models e.g. with a negative binomial distribution and a log-link.
I analyse these using as follows:

```
mod = glmmTMB(count ~ resource*day + (1|plot), data = df, family = nbinom1)
```

To compare the slope of specific resources I use:

```
obj <- emtrends(model, pairwise ~ resource, var = “day”)
pairs(obj)
```

I would like to obtain effect sizes with confidence intervals on the response scale for a specific period. I’ve so far calculated these using a bootstrap:

```
  diff_slope <- function(model, data, var, day0, day1, levels, indices){
  d     <- data[indices, ] # allows boot to select sample
  mod1  <- update(model, data = d)
  
  newdat <- unique(subset(data, select = - day))
  
  newdat_A  <- subset(newdat, get(var) == levels[1])
  newdat_B  <- subset(newdat, get(var) == levels[2])
  
  newdat_A0 <- data.frame(newdat_A, day = day0)
  newdat_A1 <- data.frame(newdat_A, day = day1)
  
  newdat_B0 <- data.frame(newdat_B, day = day0)
  newdat_B1 <- data.frame(newdat_B, day = day1)
  
  diff_A = mean(predict(mod1, newdata = newdat_A1, type = "response") -
                  predict(mod1, newdata = newdat_A0, type = "response"))
  
  diff_B = mean(predict(mod1, newdata = newdat_B1, re.form = NA, type = "response") -
                  predict(mod1, newdata = newdat_B0, re.form = NA, type = "response"))
  
  diff = diff_B - diff_A
  diff
}


boot_obj <- boot(data= df, statistic=diff_slope,
                 R=2000, model = mod,
                 var = "resource",
                 levels = c("R1", "R2"),
                 day0 = 1, day1 = 8)

boot_ci <- boot.ci(boot_obj, conf = 0.95, type = "basic")
```

However, unlike emtrends, which applies a Tukey test, this bootstrap does not account for multiple testing.

**Do you know how I can in this case create a confidence interval that applies a Tukey correction (or something similar)?**

EDIT:
I have edited the diff_slope function slightly, so that newdat_A only the plots with resource A contains and likewise newdat_B only the plots with resource B.

In addition, from [these slides](https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/UG/SM/STAT3022/r/current/Lecture/lecture16_2020JC.html#7), I understand that I can apply a Bonferroni correction by altering the confidence level as follows:

> 1-alpha/number of comparisons.

In my case with only three comparisons, I can therefore calculate the Bonferroni-adjusted CIs as follows

```
boot_ci_bonferroni <- boot.ci(boot_obj, conf = 1-0.05/3, type = "basic")
```

Bonferroni is however too conservative when many comparisons are made. Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: What happened to the answer that I just wanted to thank for and comment on?

Comment: I took it down because I didn't think it was right.

Comment: Just to be more specific, I tried it on an example and the CIs were way too narrow, though wider than ones I constructed the same way without correction. Conceptually it seems right, and the uncorrected ones were close to the ones constructed from just percentiles, so not sure what went wrong. I'll look a bit further, vut so far staring at it for new insights has not revealed anything to me.