# Bootstrapped Confidence Intervals controlling for FWER?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, matlab, bonferroni

I'm currently using the **bootci** package in MATLAB to compute bootstrapped confidence intervals. I have data for two variables and I'm interested in comparing differences in means of these variables. However, I'm unsure whether and how to control for multiple hypothesis testing when computing these intervals. Any guidance on this?

```
n = 1000;  % Number of data points
rng(42);   % Set seed for reproducibility
x1 = randn(n, 1);  % Random data for group 1
x2 = randn(n, 1);  % Random data for group 2
% Function to compute the difference of means
boot_func = @(x1, x2) mean(x1) - mean(x2);
% Bootstrap resampling and calculation of confidence intervals
boot_samples = 10000;  % Number of bootstrap samples
boot_ci = bootci(boot_samples, {boot_func, x1, x2}, 'type', 'per');
% Multiple Hypothesis testing?
% Bonferroni, Holm, Step Down?
```

A similar question was asked for R (unanswered) here.
[How to adjust (bootstrapped) confidence intervals for multiple testing in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/507610/how-to-adjust-bootstrapped-confidence-intervals-for-multiple-testing-in-r)

Comment: Maybe this article can help? https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10543406.2011.607751